# How to read list from JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

```
public  class Transaction
    {
        public string Day_of_Week { get; set; }
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public int Sent_from { get; set; }
        public int number_of_merit { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }

    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int Sent_to { get; set; }
        public int Total_Received_Merit { get; set; }
        public  List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
        var  json = wc.DownloadString("xxxxxxx"); 
        var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(json);

       foreach (var item in m )
       {
           Console.WriteLine(item.Transactions);
       }
        }
       


    }
```

I want to print the content of "Transaction" but I can't really figure out why I can't access Transactions items (day of week, month, post, etc..), any thoughts?

Sent_to and total received merit are printed properly.

Comment: Can you please add example json?

Comment: Also `item.Transactions` is a `List<Transaction>` so you need another `foreach`(for example).

Comment: @GuruStron That did it, thanks!

Comment: @CSharpdocsz was glad to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one more `foreach` loop to accomplish this.

```
            foreach (var item in m)
            {
                foreach (var tran in item.Transactions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tran.Month);
                }
            }
```